# WCF client and server need to translate class names/namespaces

Tags: c#, wcf

Imagine a WCF service running on IIS. It has one method which returns one type:

```
namespace TheServer
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IServerSideInterface
    {
        [OperationContract]
        ServerSideResultType CreateParentData(ServerSideParameterType input);
    }
}
```

However, on the client I wish to have:

```
    namespace TheClient
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IClientSideInterface
    {
        [OperationContract]
        ClientSideResultType CreateParentData(ClientSideParameterType input);
    }
}
```

It's actually slightly more complicated as I want it to be asynchronous, but one step at a time.

I wish to use a ChannelFactory to communicate from the client to the server.

It is here I am stuck.

The next bit of code uses the type names I'm using in my sample.

```
    ...
    private readonly IClientWcfServiceChannel _client;

    public ChanFacWcfServiceMainPageViewModel()
    {
        var f = new ChannelFactory<IClientWcfServiceChannel>(new BasicHttpBinding(),
            new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:50001/WcfService.svc"));

        _client = f.CreateChannel();
        FireCommand = new RelayCommand(Execute);   
    }

    private void Callback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        var result2 = _client.EndCreateParentData(ar);
        //var result = ((IClientWcfService)ar.AsyncState).EndCreateParentData(ar);
        Result = result2.ToString();
    }

    private void Execute()
    {
        _client.BeginCreateParentData(ClientWcfServiceStartUpMode.StartUpLater, Callback, SynchronizationContext.Current);
    }
```

This gives me a "not found" exception in the Callback method.

How do I map from the server type to the client type? They are essentially identical except for the names. On the server everything starts "Server" and on the client, the types were copy and pasted and renamed with "Client" at the start. The namespace also.

I do not want to use a shared type in a library common to both projects and I do not want to use svcUtil or "Add service reference" to create proxies (although I have to poke at their code).

Additional info:
VS 2012 + 4.5.

Comment: Are you trying to create a duplex (two-way) service?

Comment: Not specifically for this example, but I will be in the next step or two. For the moment I would be happy to understand in the simplest terms, how to map a server's classes to classes in the client, specifically without replicating names and namespaces.

Comment: I don't think you can.  `TheServer.IServerSideInterface` and `TheClient.IClientSideInterface` are two separate classes, even if they have the exact same code.  The client uses the contract exposed by the service's metadata to create itself.  As far as WCF is concerned, you're creating a channel with a contract of `TheClient.IClientSideInterface`, and it will look for a service that implements the same contract, not `TheServer.IServerSideInterface`.

Comment: Cheers Tim. It was harder than I expected. I think you're right, except you can have a dotnet contract (interface) with a different wcf interface via the name/namespace set in the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I've got it to work. There were a number of issues mixing together to make it more complicated than I expected. The end result uses a Silverlight client. Silverlight has some specific restrictions in that you have to use async calls for services. It throws an exception if you try to access a synchronous called service.

EDIT: Added some DataMember attributes.

So on the server I annotated the interfaces and classes:

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "MyServiceClass", Namespace = "Ian.Server")]
public interface IServerWcfService
{
    [OperationContract]
    ServerWcfServiceParentData CreateParentData(ServerWcfServiceStartUpMode mode);
}

[DataContract(Name = "ServiceChildData", Namespace = "Ian.Server")]
public class ServerWcfServiceParentData
{
    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<ServerWcfServiceChildData> Children { get; private set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "ServiceChildData", Namespace = "Ian.Server")]
public class ServerWcfServiceChildData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public ServerWcfServiceChildData NestedChild { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "ServiceStartUpMode", Namespace = "Ian.Server")]
public enum ServerWcfServiceStartUpMode
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "None")]
    None,
    [EnumMember(Value = "StartUpNow")]
    StartUpNow,
    [EnumMember(Value = "StartUpLater")]
    StartUpLater
}
```

On the client I created the same classes but with my new names and similar annotations:

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "MyServiceClass", Namespace = "Ian.Server")]
public interface IClientWcfService
{
    [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true, Action = "Ian.Server/MyServiceClass/CreateParentData",
        ReplyAction = "Ian.Server/MyServiceClass/CreateParentDataResponse")]
    IAsyncResult BeginCreateParentData(ClientWcfServiceStartUpMode mode, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);

    ClientWcfServiceParentData EndCreateParentData(IAsyncResult result);
}

public interface IClientWcfServiceChannel : IClientWcfService, IClientChannel
{
}

[DataContract(Name = "ServiceChildData", Namespace = "Ian.Server")]
public class ClientWcfServiceParentData
{
    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<ClientWcfServiceChildData> Children { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "ServiceChildData", Namespace = "Ian.Server")]
public class ClientWcfServiceChildData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public ClientWcfServiceChildData NestedChild { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "ServiceStartUpMode", Namespace = "Ian.Server")]
public enum ClientWcfServiceStartUpMode
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "None")]
    None,
    [EnumMember(Value = "StartUpNow")]
    StartUpNow,
    [EnumMember(Value = "StartUpLater")]
    StartUpLater
}
```

Notice the async changes for the service contract. We have a Begin and End pair with the async flag set. Only the Begin has an OperationContract attribute.

Also I set the Action and ReplyAction to the values I found in the wsdl.

I have a viewmodel in my Silverlight App, the important parts for calling the service are here:

```
    private string _result;
private readonly IClientWcfServiceChannel _client;

public ChanFacWcfServiceMainPageViewModel()
{
    var f = new ChannelFactory<IClientWcfServiceChannel>(new BasicHttpBinding(),
        new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:50001/WcfService.svc"));

    _client = f.CreateChannel();
    FireCommand = new RelayCommand(Execute);   
}

private void Callback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    var context = ar.AsyncState as SynchronizationContext;
    if (context == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("wtf");
    }
    var result2 = _client.EndCreateParentData(ar);
    context.Post(o => { Result = result2.ToString(); }, null);
}

private void Execute()
{
    _client.BeginCreateParentData(ClientWcfServiceStartUpMode.StartUpLater, Callback, SynchronizationContext.Current);
}
```

It's quite scrappy still, passing the SyncContext around and so on, but it does work.

For this example it just returns the type name to the view, which is pointless but proves it has a) returned something and b) that the type is the type I expected.

Importantly there is no shared code. Nothing exists in a common Portable library for example.

Comment: This is pretty interesting, but I wonder why you're the first person to need to do this.

Comment: I've used WCF for years and never had a need to do this before, so I guess it's not so common. There are other options, you can add a service reference or use SvcUtil. There's a specific version of SvcUtil for Silverlight (SvcUtilSL iirc) which crashes a lot making it next to useless for me. Adding a service reference works fine, except at the moment it is importing a bucket load of types I don't want and they are polluting the client code base. They cause some really bizarre errors where one has an implicit conversion to another, so I want control. You can also add an xml file to do mapping..

Comment: Have you reported any of the crashes to Microsoft? What did they say?

Comment: .. One part of our problem is the legacy code base has issues which amplified the pollution caused by the service references. It's all a bit complicated, but I've learned a lot this evening including some alternatives to this. You can add a NamespaceMapping to the .svcmap file. Still din't quite do what I wanted though.

Comment: I probably should report them. I just sort of assumed it was half finished which is quite common on the Silverlight side of things generally.

Comment: Ok, but did you report the crashes? "Those who don't report bugs are condemned to suffer from them"

Comment: I did not, but I will tomorrow. Although the quote in my case would read "Those who don't report bugs condemn others to suffer from them" ;)

Comment: Well, yeah, but I didn't want to presume on your altruism :-)